# Solving a proof for a tautology same as solving for actual value?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

If you are given a claim such as the following, is it correct to set x=7 as a given and prove for a tautology? If it is, is it better practice to set x=7 as the goal here, and instead prove for that?

$$Claim: \ Suppose \ x \ is \ a \ real\ number \ and \ x \neq 4. \ If \ \frac{2x-5}{x-4} = 3 \ then \ x = 7.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting x= 7 and showing that $\frac{2(7)- 5}{7- 4}= \frac{9}{3}= 3$ would prove the "converse", "if x= 7 then $\frac{2x- 5}{x- 4}= 3$".  To show that "if $\frac{2x- 5}{x- 4}= 3$ then $x= 7$ by setting x= 7 you would have to have already proved that there is only **one** value of x such that $\frac{2x- 5}{x- 4}= 3$.

Simpler is to **solve** the equation: Given $\frac{2x- 5}{x- 4}= 3$, multiply both sides by x- 4: $2x- 5= 3(x- 4)= 3x- 12$.  Then $3x- 2x= x= 12- 5= 7$.

Comment: Great explanation, didn't realize you would need to first prove there is only one value of x that would make that true.